# How do I get .to_datetime() to stop offsetting by UTC in string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting a timestamp given as a string from a .CSV file. It is in this format:

```
2016-06-06T09:30:00.000856632-04:00
```

When I use `.to_datetime()` to convert it to a date object, it offsets the UTC time. In this example, 9:30AM becomes 1:30PM:

```
2016-06-06 13:30:00.000856632
```

I read the documentation for the function and thought setting UTC = False as a parameter would fix this but it just offsets the time by a different amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string has a -4 hours offset. Remove that before conversion:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime("2016-06-06T09:30:00.000856632-04:00"[:-6])
Timestamp('2016-06-06 09:30:00.000856632')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the offset of 4 hours with `timedelta` after the conversion:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime("2016-06-06T09:30:00.000856632-04:00") + datetime.timedelta(hours = -4)
# Timestamp('2016-06-06 09:30:00.000856632')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [`.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) has a format argument.

> format : string, default None
>
> strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.

```
.to_datetime(format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Will yield

> '11/03/2016'

The `format` follows the same Python `datetime` format that is used in [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). For a complete list of time format parameters, [see this reference](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: Does the formatting prevent the time from being offset? My issue is not the format but the time zone offset

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the documentation.